# need a format of BibTex

Tags: bibtex

I am beginner in Latex. I need a BibTex format in which:

1. The name of authors are sorted by family name, the given name is abbreviated and given name is first, then family name ; i.e. we see S. Akbari and F. Belardo and S. Akbari is upper than F. Belardo.
2. Nothing be italic. (names of books and article and etc. ... be normal)
3. After the last author of a bibitem, it doesn't have a dot.

Can anybody introduce me a format?

Best regards,

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your description fails to address a lot of formatting issues. E.g., where should the publication year be placed: immediately after the author block, at the end, or somewhere else? For entries of type `@book`, should the publisher be listed before or after the publisher's address? E.g., "Springer, Berlin" or "Berlin: Springer"? How should citation call-outs appear: In numeric style or in author-year style? Etc, etc. Your best bet is probably to familiarize yourself with the `makebst` utility (open a command window and type "latex makebst") and create a bespoke bib style.

Comment: Thank you. The things that you pointed to are not important for me. Just the ones that listed.

Comment: Thanks. I got the answer